# Are dynamically created controls in VB.net created on the heap or the stack?

Tags: vb.net, memory, optimization

I'm experimenting with a Goal Tracking application that generates a list of goals the user has set. I'm currently just using labels as placeholders for whatever I'll use later on. My question is, as I populate this form with the labels, are they being created on the heap or the stack?

The generation loop is running every time the form is loaded, so I can't really deduce for myself. (edit: numberOfGoals is a global variable in a separate module file that the whole project has access to.) If the objects were being created on the heap, does that mean that there is a more efficient way of populating the form? Maybe keeping a global list of goals generated in a similar way and when this form is loaded just load from that list onto the stack?

I apologize if the question seems ambiguous. I'm new to both VB.net and programming in general. Thank you everyone for your time.

```
Private Sub Tracker_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If numberOfGoals > 0 Then
        For counter As Integer = 0 To numberOfGoals Step 1
            Dim newLabel As New Label

            'Set control settings
            With newLabel
                .Name = "Label" & counter
                .Text = "Label " & counter + 1
                .Visible = True
                .Location = New Point(20, 10 + 25 * counter)
            End With

            'Activate form and add control
            Me.Activate()
            ActiveForm.Controls.Add(newLabel)
        Next
    ElseIf numberOfGoals = 0 Then
        Dim newLabel As New Label
        With newLabel
            .Text = "You have no goals set yet."
            .Location = New Point(20, 35)
            .AutoSize = True
        End With

        Me.Activate()
        ActiveForm.Controls.Add(newLabel)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you notice significant performance issue when you loading form? If not - don't waste your time on it - (unless you asking this in learning purposes). In winforms one of the most expensive operation is drawing controls - so even you save your labels in some global collection - every time you add them to form , they need to be drawn.

Comment: Another suggestion - instead of creating labels and calculating their location, try to use `DataGridView` which perfectly supports showing collection data.

Comment: Well, it's a bit of both. I'm making the app to learn, although I am curious about the memory implications here. I didn't know about the DataGridView though, I'll look it up right now, thank you

Comment: If you need to know then you are doing it wrong.  Heap, the Control class is a reference type, not a value type.  You'll have to stop relying on the Load event crutch, this code belongs in the constructor of the class.  It matters, hard-coding the Location property like that does not work well on modern monitors with a high DPI setting.

Comment: @HansPassant great advice, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Those labels are being created on the heap. The concept of memory-management and optimization in the .NET Framework is actually pretty fascinating; I've included a link below. Basically, objects in the .NET Framework tend to be very expensive. At the very least, I would include some type of user-check to prevent the creation of too many goals. This obviously has practical benefits too, as chances of success tend to increase proportionality with focus (:.

As for the second part of your question, I'm guessing you're referring to storing a reference to each dynamically-created control and going through and deleting each one in your clean up. Depending on how long your application is running, this might not be a bad idea. This is actually sort of how early implementations of memory management were built.

Essentially, two linked lists were created. The first linked list included all of the dynamically created objects. The second list was populated by analyzing what objects could be accessed through the active pointers. If they were reachable they were added to the list. If the weren't reachable, this meant that they were no longer being used (or they couldn't be used, since there was no way to access them). The second list was compared with the first and whatever objects where on the first list but not on the second were then 'garbage collected', as it were. So in essence, you've arrived at the primitive implementation of garbage collection, congrats!

Here is a great article about the .NET Framework's memory system, specifically the overheard that stems from the creation of items: (https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/object-overhead-the-hidden-net-memory-allocation-cost/)